# can I call a method in suds dynamically

Tags: python, suds

Firstly ... I'm new in python and suds..

Now I wanna dynamically call a method provided by an unknown webService

I do not know what services it provides beforehand

the normal way to call a method I know is like this:

```
client.service.getWeatherInfo()
```

but how can I call write the code before I know it provides the method "getWeatherInfo"

I assume it could be like this or what

```
client.service['getWeatherInfo']
```

anybody know the way to call it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
getattr(client.service, 'getWeatherInfo')()
```

Comment: I followed your way and looked through the mannul of 'getattr'...thanks